# Spring XML configuration doesn't working -

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I'm learing how to create apps in spring.

Firstly I've configured app in Java Config using *AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer* and it works.

Now I try to configure MVC App using XML and result is HTTP 404 :/

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="test" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

HomeController

```
package test.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller     
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello!");
        model.addAttribute("tagline", "First XML Config");

        return "welcome";
    }   
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.bambo</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>
</project>
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcZKT.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7gcT.png)

I've tried different things since 5 hours but no result.

Comment: Are you sure that the your app context start correctly? I want ask it because I don't see the name of your root application context probably the problem could be in a wrong instantiation of root context.

Comment: Do you mean <context-param> in web.xml ?

I use this tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-mvc-web-project-example

And in spring-core-config.xml is only component-scan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have many details but starting from our comment I can say this.

Seeing your web.xml I see that you don't configure the root application context. Configuring the dispatcher servlet, you configure the web context. The key point in my words is that for web application configuring the dispatcher servlet you configure a web context and if you need, adding the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` in your web xml you ask at Spring to add a root application context that will be the parent of your web context.

However in your web.xml you don't add the location for the root application context xml file and if you don't have a file called applicationContext.xml under WEB-INF (official docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/ chapter 6.15.4 Convenient ApplicationContext instantiation for web applications), Spring don't find the configuration file. For overcame this issue you can add a paramiter in your web.xml like below:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

It is clear that adding

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in your web.xml you supply the path of your root application context configuration and all works fine.

You could consider, if you don't need of a separation of web context and root context,you can erase the listener and configure the bean of your root context as bean of web context.
Many web app like Alfresco use this strategy.

**Update for answareing at comment:**

In my opinion a correct way is configure service, repository and more in general buisiness-application-service bean, in a root context that you configure inserting the litener in your web.xml and controller/rest endpoint and more in general all the web-layer(view resolver, interceptor and so on) in the web context created by dispatcher servlet.

Say that if you don't insert  configuration for servlet and/or listener spring use the your default configuration conventions if you provide   you can overaide this conventions.

in many case you can see exampel over internet that use a configuration like below:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                            version="3.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


....
</web-app>
```

but remember the my answare, for web application is mandatory have a web context created by dispatcer servlet that if you want can override the location of xml file, but been a better approach have a separated context on internet you see always the configuration wit listener but it isn't mandatory.

I hope that this can help you and clarifying the your mind.

Comment: Ok, thank U very much. So Spring need <context-param> even if application-context.xml doesn't exit ?

And in future in application-context.xml I will configure for example Spring Web Flow etc. yes ?

Well, so why many authors don't include this <context-param> in web.xml ?

Comment: I update the my answare and i consider that probably clarifies the your doubts

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, but it looks like you are trying to hit the base url at /test/.  If you are using the internal view resolver shouldn't you be hitting /test/welcome since it has to map back to the jsp?

Comment: Yes, I want to hit base url at /test/. "welcome" is name of .jsp file. As You see I set suffix and prefix so /test/ is mapping to /test/ welcome.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I added to web.xml and it works :

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

but I dont understand why it works ? Why do I have to add dispatcher-servlet.xml twice ?

I read "Spring in Practise" and author doesn't use  and  in web.xml. What is going on ?